# Can I use netstandard1.* libraries in netstandard2.0 project?

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

Since the major version number has changed I suppose that netstandard2.0 contains changes that are incompatible with netstandard1.*.

Are there any restrictions in using netstandard1.* libraries from the netstandard2.0 project?

Comment: I saw a warning from the netcore devs that 1.5 and 1.6 were a problem, they did not cover them completely in 2.0.  Without going into detail.  The ultimate arbiter is the compiler, it lets you know about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any netstandard1.* library with netstandard2.0 project.
From [.NET Standard versioning rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard):

> Additive: .NET Standard versions are logically concentric circles: higher versions incorporate all APIs from previous versions. There are no breaking changes between versions.

and [specific for .NET Standart 2. breaking change clarification](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-about-the-breaking-change-between-net-standard-1x-and-20):

> Based on community feedback, we decided not to make .NET Standard 2.0 be a breaking change from 1.x. Instead, .NET Standard 2.0 is a strict superset of .NET Standard 1.6. The plan for handling .NET Framework 4.6.1 and .NET Standard 2.0 is outlined in the spec.

---

In general the .NET Standard version of your project impact the following:

- The higher the version, the more APIs are available to you.
- The lower the version, the more platforms implement it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. On your link I found another page which details about it. https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-about-the-breaking-change-between-net-standard-1x-and-20